# Cordova (Ionic) CLI commands used during plugin development for copying plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm currently developing a Cordova plugin for use in my Ionic project. Whenever I've made changes in the plugin that I want to try out, I want to copy the updated plugin to the platforms (currently only iOS).

Currently I'm doing `rm -rf platforms/ios && cordova platform add ios`. This is however slow, and requires me to do some manual work in the generated iOS workspace.

I've tried doing `cordova prepare ios` as well, but it seems that it doesn't detect any differences in the plugins, why it doesn't copy the updated plugin.

*How can I make Cordova copy the updated plugin to the platform folders?*

Comment: does [`cordova prepare <platform>`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/#cordova-prepare-command) work?

Comment: @SurajRao sorry I forgot to mention this in my post. I've tried doing that, with the `--verbose` flag set. However, Cordova doesn't seem to think that there are any differences to the plugins, hence it wont copy the plugin.

Comment: better to include that part in the question itself

Comment: Updated question!